# Getting nullpointer on swapcursor after prolonged inactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

My loaders, fragment and content provider work fine.  All my lists can updated OK, but after a prolonged period of inactivity (main activity gets paused), if I reactivite the app, I get a null pointer on swapsursor call

```
public class ListeFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private ListItemSelectListener listeSelectListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listeSelectListener = (ListItemSelectListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " doit implementer ListItemSelectListener");
        }
    }

    // public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // int scroll = this.getSelectedItemPosition();
    // outState.putInt("POS", scroll); }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.e ("Resto", "pos="+position+" Rowid= "+id);
        listeSelectListener.onItemSelected(position, id);      
    }

    private static final int RESTO_RECENT_LOADER = 0x01;
    private static final int RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER = 0x02;
    private static final int RESTO_HIGH_LOADER = 0x03;
    private static final int RESTO_SEARCH_LOADER = 0x04;
    // private static final String AUTHORITY = "ca.usimage.resto.RestoProvider";
    // private static final String RESTOS_BASE_PATH = "restos";

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    public void afficheList(int loader_id, String query) {
        Log.e ("Resto", "loader_id= "+loader_id);
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString("search_query", query);
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(loader_id, mBundle, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            String[] uiBindFrom = { RestoDatabase.COL_ETAB, RestoDatabase.COL_MONTANT };
            int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.TextView01, R.id.Montant };
            // default loader on startup is RECENT_LOADER
            LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
            if (lm.getLoader(RESTO_RECENT_LOADER) != null) {
                lm.initLoader(RESTO_RECENT_LOADER, null, this);
            }

            // if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,
                null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            // }
            // this.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("POS"));
        }
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = { RestoDatabase.ID, RestoDatabase.COL_ETAB,  RestoDatabase.COL_MONTANT };
        switch (id){
        case RESTO_RECENT_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, "date_infraction DESC");

        case RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI_GROUPBY, projection, null, null,"etablissement ASC");

        case RESTO_HIGH_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, "montant DESC");

        case RESTO_SEARCH_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, "etablissement like \"%" + args.getString("search_query") + "%\"", null, "etablissement ASC");

        default: return null;
        }
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        // position cursor at top of list
        // this.setSelection(0);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Seems like there's a problem with the actionbar as I'm trying to have a default selected tab which calls a loader at startup.

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ;
        setContentView(R.layout.liste);
        final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();

        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ab.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            tab_pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("tabState");               
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recente).setTabListener(this),0,false);
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_alpha).setTabListener(this),1,false);
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_fortes).setTabListener(this),2,false);
            ab.setSelectedNavigationItem(tab_pos);       
        } else {       
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recente).setTabListener(this),0,true);
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_alpha).setTabListener(this),1,false);
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_fortes).setTabListener(this),2,false);
        }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // position cursor at top of list if user retaps a tab
        ListeFragment listeFrg =  (ListeFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listeFragment);
        listeFrg.setSelection(0);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ListeFragment listeFrg = (ListeFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listeFragment);

        int position = tab.getPosition();
        Log.e ("resto", "pos= "+position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:        
            listeFrg.afficheList(RESTO_RECENT_LOADER, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            listeFrg.afficheList(RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            listeFrg.afficheList(RESTO_HIGH_LOADER, null);
            break;
        }           
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tabState", getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition());
    }
```

Comment: In which line do you get the null pointer exception?

Comment: This is my first post ever, so please excuse my not putting line numbers in the code... can't find a simple way of doing that... anyhow, the null pointer occurs here:                                         public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

Comment: Not putting line numbers is fine, but please try to indent your code next time. Otherewise it's almost impossible to read. I indented it myself just to figure out what's going on there. Another suggestion is to try to include as little code as possible, to make it easier for people to help you. Only relevant code should be included. For instance, commented out lines of code are not relevant. You should also give better tags to your questions. If you had done that, your question would have probably been answered within minutes instead of after 10 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely in `onActivityCreated`.

After a long period of inactivity, the operating system destroys your activity.
When you try to go back to your activity, it is re-created.
After `onCreated` of the activity is called, `onActivityCreated` of the fragment is called,
but you have a condition that creates the `adapter` only if `savedInstanceState` is null.
If it's not null, you don't create the `adapter`, which causes the null pointer exception later when it's accessed.

Comment: This is so obvious now... I forget why I even put that condition. Thanks for all the advice.